# Getting thumbnail of video from sdcard path but loading on gridview very slow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter

I am loading thumbnail of video sdcard path. But the thumbnail is loading too late.I am using Custom gallery.Below is my code.How can i make the thumbnail load faster.Please Answer.

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null)
    {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_album_item_photo, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgLoader);
        holder.t1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.alb_name);

        view.setTag(holder);
    } 
    else 
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    holder.t1.setText(ALBUMS_LIST.get(position).getName());
    File f = new File(ALBUMS_LIST.get(position).getCover());
    Bitmap bitmap =ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(ALBUMS_LIST.get(position).getCover(),MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);

    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


    return view;

}
static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView t1;
}
```

`

Comment: create thumbnail of video before passing data to adapter

Comment: i agree with him. And use `Bitmap bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
                video.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);`to create thumbnail

Comment: In getView() every time you are downloading the image and displaying in the listview thats why it becomes slower. For that you can use UniversalImageLoader for lazy loading of listitems

Comment: @JigneshJain Can you please tell,how can i do it.Donot know where to put this line ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail

Comment: @Aspicas Iam doing the same but not getting

Comment: I was using the picasso libarary priveusly but the thumbnail were not visible then i used ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail and the thumbnails become visible but  loads late

Comment: actually the activty that contain vedios loads late when i click on tab

Comment: when you pass url to adapter before that just download video and get thumbnail image then do it with lazy loading

Comment: can you please post a code or link to do this @JigneshJain

Comment: Just see what i'm telling first when you set your arraylist before that download video from url then take a thumb image from that video and pass that video thumb to adapter and in adapter just set thumbnail,

Answer (score -1):

I solved it mySelf using Below code and replacing with createvideoThumbnail code:

```
        ContentResolver crThumb = mContext.getContentResolver();
    BitmapFactory.Options opt=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inSampleSize = 1;
    int id=(int) data.get(position).getId();
    Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, opt);

    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(curThumb);
```